# Display views exposed filter in sidebar

Tags: drupal-7

I Want to display exposed filter of any view page into the left sidebar of theme, anyone can suggest it is possible or not, if possible please explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible you can you `Exposed form in block` option in views to get filters as block
Please follow the mentioned steps https://www.drupal.org/node/2018903#comment-10028345

or follow below screenshots
1.
[image]

1. save the view

2.goto admin/structure/blocks/ and find the filter your block filter

[image]

Place it the region where you want. Thank you.